# PUT in laravel API

Tags: laravel, api, controller, routes, put

I'm studying api rest with laravel, I was able to implement all methods except PUT. Although the routes and controllers are correctly configured a response to a request using the PUT method is "laravel put Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.", [As now image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzmvg.png).

here is the method code in the controller in app/Http/Controllers/LivroController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)  {

$livro = $request->isMethod('put') ? Livro::findOrFail($request->livro_id) : new Livro;

$livro->id = $request->input('livro_id');
$livro->nome = $request->input('nome');
$livro->descricao = $request->input('descricao');
$livro->user_id =  1; //$request->user()->id;

if($livro->save()) {
  return new LivroResource($livro);
}}
```

here is the route code in /routes/api.php:

```
Route::put('livro', 'LivroController@store');
```

Comment: is a get route working fine in api.php ?

Comment: yes the api has routes to get, post delete working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create new data, you should use post method,

```
Route::post('livro', 'LivroController@store');

public function store(Request $request)  {
```

If you want to update exist data you should use put method,

```
Route::put('livro/{id}', 'LivroController@update');

public function update(Request $request, $id)  {
```

You can use this package https://github.com/durmus-aydogdu/laravel-resource for rest calls. This package highly customizable for rest and resource calls.

Comment: sorry, it should be put, 

Route::put('livro/{id}', 'LivroController@update');

Answer (score 4):

change your postman method to POST and then add new parameter in your Body :

```
"_method" : PUT
```

This is because HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or  DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form

Comment: Did you mean in the controllers body? or the requisition? I'm using the postman https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzmvg.png

Comment: I tried "_method" : PUT, "_method" : "PUT", "_method" : put and "_method" : "put" the answer is the same.

Comment: No, I did it that way: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OJfE7vpkp-gVQY9DndAYJucBTMlT_7Og

Comment: Change your method to post and give it a try

Comment: new erro: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'nome' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `livros` (`id`, `nome`, `descricao`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , 1, 2018-06-07 22:41:13, 2018-06-07 22:41:13))

Comment: well your problem with accessing PUT method is all set

Answer (score 0):

Is better that you use controllers type resources and for this case the put method. Also you should validate the request. For example:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

  $livro = Livro::findOrFail($id);
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'livro_id' => 'required',
    'nome' => 'required',
    'descricao' => 'required',
  ]);
  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->messages()],Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
  }else{
    $livo->update($request->all());
    return response()->json(['livro'=>$livro], Response::HTTP_OK);
  }

}
```